# Як правильно назвати кнопку, що знаходиться "на боковій стороні"?

Tags: вибір-слова

За СУМ, якщо йдеться про частини предмета, треба вживати слово *бік*.

> **БІК**, боку, чол.
>
> 2. Яка-небудь сторона, стінка, площина предмета.

У книжних стилях усталилися стандартизовані словосполучення з іменником бік, напр.: лицьовий, зворотний, тіньовий, позитивний бік, бути на чийомусь боці, погляд з боку, з усіх боків, привернути на свій бік тощо.

А як сформулювати опис можливостей електричного пристрою, якщо кнопки керування знаходяться "на боковой стороне"? На бічному боці? Звучить кострубато. *Збоку* не підходить, тому що на лицьовому боці також є кнопки в центрі й по краях.

Comment: на *лівому боці*, звучить досить однозначно, *бокових сторін* дві, щонайменше.

Comment: @Yola, я думаю, що Oksana Çeliker шукає слово/словосполучення, яке може позначати одночасно лівий і правий бік, але не інші.

Comment: Теоретично є словосполучення «профільний портет» і «профільний зріз/переріз», але «профільний бік / профільна сторона» не кажуть, бо слово «профільний» має іншу семантику.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замість *лицьового боку* можна вживати *спереду*. Тоді для позначення двох бокових сторін, можна вживати *зліва* і *справа*, якщо ж треба вказати на обидва боки, то *збоку*. Наприклад,

> Спереду екран, а з (обох) боків кнопки керування.